# Why this f# echo server can't be connected by many clients?

Tags: f#

I write this echo server:

```
let listener=new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),2000)

let rec loop (client : TcpClient,sr : StreamReader, sw : StreamWriter) = 
async {
        let line=sr.ReadLine()
        sw.WriteLine(line)
        if line="quit" then
            client.Close()
        else

            return! loop(client,sr,sw)
}

let private startLoop (listener:TcpListener) = 
    while true do
        let client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        let stream = client.GetStream()
        let sr = new StreamReader(stream)
        let sw = new StreamWriter(stream)
        sw.AutoFlush <- true
        sw.WriteLine("welcome")
        Async.Start(loop (client,sr,sw))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
 listener.Start()
 startLoop(listener)
 0
```

when I open one or two telnet window to test it,it works fine

but when I write this test program to test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 2000);
            Console.WriteLine(client.Connected);
            client.close();
        }
    }
```

the test program return one or two true,but the server raise an exception:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException：An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

in line 12:let line=sr.ReadLine()

and client raise the exception:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException：Because the target computer actively refused, unable to connect
at line 16:var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 2000);

I don't know why,please help me

Comment: No deletes this time, OK? It's hard to read a question that gets spontaneously deleted

Comment: As for the problem, `Async.Start(loop (client,sr,sw))` captured the *variables*, not the stored values. `loop` sees whatever is in the `sr` and `sw` variables, which could *easily* be a reader for another client, or even a closed client

Comment: Thanks!So how to fix it?I don't want to let loop function to have the params:client,sr,sw,but I need to write to the client a "welcome" first when them connected to the server.Actually I don't know how to write a f# concurrence tcp server,and I can't find a good example or project good to learn,can you teach me one?

Comment: and I think the sr and sw belongs to a decided client than other client can't use

Comment: You'd have the same problem in C# - the *lambda* captures the variable, not the value. It means, when it executes it reads whatever is in the variable at the time of execution, not when the lambda was constructed. Pass *only* the client and retrieve the stream,reader/writer inside `loop`.

Comment: Ok...but how to write "welcome" when a client connected?because the function loop is a recursion function,so if I write sr.writeLine("welcome") at the top of the loop function,the server will tell the client many times welcome,not only once

Comment: I change the code,write sr and sw in the loop funciton.but the error is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the client opens a connection and then immediately closes it.

The server however expects a `"quit"` message from the client before it will terminate the connection. So the server sends a `"welcome"` to the client, then enters the `loop`. Inside the loop, `sr.ReadLine()` is called, which waits for the client to send something over the wire.

The client never sends anything. It closes the connection. Therefore, the server's call to `ReadLine` aborts with the a `SocketException` (forcibly closed...). And you do not handle this exception, so the server dies.

Then the client tries to connect once again, with no server listening anymore. The client can't connect and you see another `SocketException` (actively refused...).

You should guard your server code against clients that disconnect without saying `"quit"` first.